# How to pass lambda expression to where statement with comparison

Tags: c#, lambda

Let's say I have this class

```
public class Person
{
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to write a method that can return a list of users based on the property of the Person and the comparison filed.

```
private List<Person> GetResult(Func<Person, object> p, string v)
{
       List<Person> data = GetResultsFromDb();
       return data.Where(p == v);
}
```

For example, if I want to get all the People who are called Mike, I can say

```
var result = GetResult(a => a.Name, "Mike");
```

Or if I want to get results based on phone number I can say

```
var result = GetResult(a => a.PhoneNumber, 123);
```

However I'm getting

```
Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'Expression<Func<Person, object>>' and string
```

Comment: try `GetResult<T>(Func<Person, T> p, T v)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of `p` is a delegate. This type does not compare well with a `string` (hence your error message). You need to call the delegate to get a value. However, a return type of object is not optimal for a comparison. So you should make your method generic. Now that you are generic, you can't use the equality operator `==`, but you can use `Equals`. And finally you need to call `ToList` to match the return type of the method:

```
private List<Person> GetResult<T>(Func<Person, T> p, T v)
{
       List<Person> data = GetResultsFromDb();
       return data.Where(item => p(item).Equals(v)).ToList();
}
```

Since the parameter `v` is of type `T`, `T` can be inferred when you call the method. That means you can omit the type parameter, so you can use `GetResult(a => a.Name, "Mike")` instead of `GetResult<string>(a => a.Name, "Mike")`.

Some .NET Pros could complain now that you don't need the method to be generic when you call `Equals`, since `Equals` is defined on `Object`. You could also point out the fact that comparison of `null` values will not work and that an `IEquatable` implementations are not given any special consideration. If you want to dodge all of these complaints, you can use an `EqualityComparer` for the comparison:

```
private List<Person> GetResult<T>(Func<Person, T> p, T v)
{
       List<Person> data = GetResultsFromDb();
       return data.Where(item => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(p(item), v)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: And also need to override Equals method in person class, to return true in case PersonId equals other PersonId field (PK)

Comment: @Oscar: There is no comparison of `Person` instances, so `Equals` does not need to be overwritten.

Answer (score -2):

See code below.  You had p  being used for two different purposes

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private List<Person> GetResult(Func<Person, object> p, string v)
        {
            List<Person> data = GetResultsFromDb();
            return data.Where(x => x.Name == v).ToList();
        }

        private List<Person> GetResultsFromDb()
        {
            return new List<Person>() {
                new Person() { Name = "Mike"},
                new Person() { Name = "John"},
                new Person() { Name = "Mike"}
            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you you need `p` parameter in your `GetResult` method?

Comment: `GetResult` should not be specific to only `name` which doesn't satisfy the requirement of the question

Comment: I don't need p, just didn't delete if function needs p for other purposes.  Not really part of the question.  Nothing said results should be general.